# How to get user Stream<QuerySnapshot> after signing in to app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, firebase-authentication

I have an issue with firebase and flutter. I'm building app with signing in and displaying list of expenses from collection, which name is user id. When the user signs in, he will see list with items from his collection. I used Stream method. The problem is that before user signs in, stream recieves null id and the app crashes. Is there any way to set this stream after user signs in? I will be thankful for any help!

This is the error

```
The following assertion was thrown building Home(dirty):
'package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart': Failed assertion: line 72 pos 12: 'path != null': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was
    Home 
lib\screens\wrapper.dart:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#2      Firestore.collection 
package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart:72
#3      DatabaseService.expenses 
package:expenses_app/services/database.dart:38
#4      Home.build 
package:expenses_app/…/home/home.dart:27
#5      StatelessElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4291
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4223


this is stream in database file
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get expenses  {
    return firestoreReference.collection(uid).snapshots();
}

this is widget, which loads after user signs in

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:expenses_app/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:expenses_app/services/database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'expenses_list.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  static String currentUid;
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  void getUid() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    currentUid = user.uid;
    //print(currentUid);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getUid();

    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
      value: DatabaseService(uid: currentUid).expenses,
          child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red[400],
            title: Text('Expenses App'),
            elevation: 0.0,
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person,
                color: Colors.white,),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _auth.signOut();
                },
                label: Text('Logout',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),

              )
            ],
          ),
          body: ExpensesList(),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are building widgets before id arrive check if the id is not null before build return, if the id is null return empty container e

Comment: yes, id is null, but how to pass the id to stream later, after signing in?